# Generating JavaScript document using yuidoc with ANT script

Tags: javascript, android, ant, yui, yuidoc

I am trying to generate JavaScript documentation using yuidoc, below is my ANT script.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project default="javascriptdoc">
<property name="doc_dir" location="docs/javascript" />
<property name="src" location="assests/Siminov" />
<property name="projectname" value="Siminov Hybrid JavaScript Document Generator" />
<property name="version"  value="1.0" />
<property name="project_url" value="http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/yuidoc" />
<property name="yuidoc_home" location="yuidoc.assets" />
<property name="yuidoc_exec" location="${yuidoc_home}/bin/yuidoc.py" />
<property name="tmp_dir" location="docstmp" />
<property name="parser_in" location="${src}" />

<echo>Making sure build dir is there</echo>
<mkdir dir="${doc_dir}" />

<target name="javascriptdoc">
    <property name="parser_out" location="${doc_dir}/parsertmp" />
    <property name="generator_out" location="${doc_dir}" />
    <property name="template" location="template" />
    <property name="yuiversion" location="3.0.0" />

    <echo>generating documentation</echo>

    <exec executable="${yuidoc_exec}">
      <arg value="${parser_in}"/>
      <arg value="-p"/>
      <arg value="${parser_out}"/>
      <arg value="-o" />
      <arg value="${generator_out}" />
      <arg value="-t" />
      <arg value="${template}" />
      <arg value="-m" />
      <arg value="${projectname}" />
      <arg value="-Y" />
      <arg value="${yuiversion}" />
      <arg value="-v" />
      <arg value="${version}" />
      <arg value="-u" />
      <arg value="$project_url" />
    </exec>

</target>
```

My project looks like

[image: Android Project Screenshot]

While running ANT script it is giving me error:

```
Buildfile: H:\Siminov Workspace\SIMINOV-HYBRID\yuidoc.xml
     [echo] Making sure build dir is there
javascriptdoc:
     [echo] generating documentation

BUILD FAILED
H:\Workspace\projectname\yuidoc.xml:25: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "H:\Workspace\projectname\yuidoc.assets\bin\yuidoc.py": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Total time: 415 milliseconds
```

Comment: You should check with the verbose mode of Ant that the launched command is what you expect: `ant -v`. Then google says the error raised maybe be something related to a python library not properly loaded.

Answer (score 1):

`<exec>` needs to point at the Python executable, not at a file containing Python source code:

```
<exec executable="C:\Python26\python.exe">
    <arg file="${yuidoc_exec}" />
    <arg value="${parser_in}"/>
    <!-- the rest of the task as before... -->
</exec>
```